# How to update data in the linked list using Java in GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, linked-list

I am currently doing a book inventory system, so the user has an option to update the number of copies of the book after they input it into the list. I have the user search the item that they want to update first. But first I want the information to be shown in each text field and update it. I have already wrote the code but it didn't work. The text field still shows nothing. May I know what is the problem here?

This is my Data class which I used to store the information:

```
public class Data {
    LinkedList list;
    String name;
    String author;
    int isbn;
    int number;
    String genre;

public Data(String name, String author, int isbn, int number, String genre)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.number = number;
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String toString()
{
    return("Book Name: "+name+"\nAuthor: "+author+"\nISBN Number: "+isbn+"\nNumber of Copies: "+number+"\nGenre: "+genre+"\n\n");
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getAuthor()
{
    return author;
}

public int getIsbn()
{
    return isbn;
}

public int getNumber()
{
    return number;
}

public String getGenre()
{
    return genre;
}

public void setNumber(int number)
{
    this.number += number;
}
}
```

And this is my update method and show info method:

```
public static void updatesearch(String sname, String name, String author, String genre, int isbn, int number, boolean found, int cnumber)
{
    Node current = head;
    if (current == null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The list is empty.");
    }
    else{
        while (current != null && !current.data.getName().equals(sname))
        {
            current = current.next;
        }
        if (current != null && current.data.getName().equals(sname)){
            found = true;
            name = current.data.getName();
            author = current.data.getAuthor();
            isbn = current.data.getIsbn();
            number = current.data.getNumber();
            genre = current.data.getGenre();
            current.data.setNumber(cnumber);
        }
        else{
            found = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The book was not found.");
        }
    }
}

public static void showinfo(String sname, String name, String author, String genre, int isbn, int number)
{
    Node current = head;
    if (current == null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The list is empty.");
    }
    else{
        while (current != null && !current.data.getName().equals(sname))
        {
            current = current.next;
        }
        if (current != null && current.data.getName().equals(sname)){
            name = current.data.getName();
            author = current.data.getAuthor();
            isbn = current.data.getIsbn();
            number = current.data.getNumber();
            genre = current.data.getGenre();
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The book was not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I have in GUI. (Under the search button)

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String sname, name=null, author=null, genre=null;
    int isbn=0, number=0;
    sname = jTextField1.getText();
    LinkedList.showinfo(sname.toUpperCase(), name, author, genre, isbn, number);
        jTextField3.setText(name);
        jTextField4.setText(author);
        jTextField5.setText(String.valueOf(isbn));
        jTextField6.setText(String.valueOf(number));
        jTextField2.setText(genre);
}
```

This is under the update button:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String sname, name=null, author=null, genre=null;
    int isbn=0, number=0, cnumber;
    boolean found=false;
    sname = jTextField1.getText();
    cnumber = Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText());
    LinkedList.updatesearch(sname.toUpperCase(),name, author, genre, isbn, number, found, cnumber);
}
```

This is how my update page looks like:

[image]

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code in the `showinfo` method doesn't do anything useful because method parameters in java are passed by value, not by reference, so changing the values of `name`, `author`, `genre`, `isbn`, or `number` does not change the values of the variables of the same name calling the method.

Comment: So what should I change ? Do I create an object for the class LinkedList? Like `LinkedList list = new LinkedList()` ?